# MonoTouch OpenGL app loses texture data when moved to background

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch OpenGL app that has a bunch of textures. When the user hits the iPhone button to move the app to the background, all my texture data seems to go away. I just see a solid color filling the triangles that I'm drawing with the textures that were loaded originally.

Any *new* textures that I load after resuming from the background state show up properly. It's just the textures that were loaded before the app was moved to the background that show up solid.

[The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH5-SW1) state that "Your application should keep textures, models and other assets in memory" when it is moved to the background. I'm not doing anything to my textures, but something is forcing them out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting.  In my application, any VBOs that I set up before going to the background are there when I return to the foreground.  While I read "in memory" in the documentation to mean "on the GPU", I wonder if textures are a different case and need to be re-bound.

Comment: Chances are that your bound textures are part of what the next paragraph discussed: components that can be easily recreated on demand.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to not use iPhoneOSGameView. That fixed all problems related to textures disappearing when my app went background. The code to manage the framebuffers and update timer yourself is pretty simple and I found the extra clarity (and working restore-from-background) to be worth the effort.

Not using iPhoneOSGameView also makes me feel better about the [application's timer actually running at full speed when the app is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719978/monotouch-iphoneosgameview-run-sleeping-too-long-between-frames):

Comment: Any chance you could post your iPhoneOSGameView replacement code? I am also running into issues with it, and I think it is better to set it up from scratch like you did...

Comment: Or perhaps share a high-level overview?